# wordpress add_action('save_post', 'my_function) not working

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I am trying to trigger an even upon saving / updating a post in wordpress... see here:

```
add_action('save_post', 'generate_location');

function generate_location($post_id) {   
    echo "hey"; 
}
```

the problem is that its not working... 
any ideas why? Syntax?

Comment: This should really be posted on [WordPress Answers](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/) instead of Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 4):

WordPress implements the [Post/Redirect/Get pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get) to avoid duplicate form submissions, so you're not going to see anything `echo`'d from a `save_post` callback.

Instead, you can do a `wp_die( 'hey' )` instead, or log something to the database or file system.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know whether you got this working, but I was having the same issue and discovered how to fix it!

in wp-includes/post.php on line 2940 (at the time of writing), this if/else is run whilst saving a post:

```
if ( !empty($page_template) && 'page' == $data['post_type'] ) {
```

You will notice that, if there is an error with the template the function stops there and save_post is never called.

In my case, the posts I was trying to save were imported from a pre-existing site. The new site had no page templates at all, so WP was still trying to save the page with the template from before, failing, and thus; save_post was never called.

I added

```
/* Template Name: Default Template */
```

to page.php, bulk edit, selected the template and saved. Remove the template name from page.php (as it shows up twice(, and now save_post is triggered every time.

This was the solution in my case anyway. i'm sure it'll affect someone else, somewhere down the line.